# javascript length property

Tags: javascript

```
return 0['toString']['length'];
```

why does it return 1

Comment: excuse me, what does that construct mean? "0" number to string and the length of that string? it's obviously 1.

Comment: @Tomasz But `1000['toString']['length']` also gives `1`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`1000['toString']` gives you the function object `Number.prototype.toString`, and in JS, function objects have a property called `length` which returns the number of arguments the function takes. In this case is 1 because `Number.prototype.toString` receives a radix argument.

```
alert(Number.prototype.toString.length) // 1
```

References:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Length
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString

Answer (score 2):

Because the length of the string `"0"` is 1 character?

Comment: He's not calling the `toString()` method, though, so the length property is for the method.

Comment: Yes, in fact my answer was not good, just a try ;) But this is a strange syntax used here (anyway, Javascript is just strance)